# Convert Microsoft Word document pages to individual jpg files with Python

Tags: python, ms-word

I would like to convert MS Word document pages into individual jpeg or png format. I am aiming to classify images.

As far as I seen, the only available method I found is zipping the MS document and extracting images that are located in the media folder. the source is [here](https://www.ubergizmo.com/how-to/extract-images-ms-word/)

Are there any python packages that are able to convert pages to individual images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only Solution that I found is converting .docx->.pdf with libreoffice and then .pdf->.jpg